# Trying to loop through a list of objects c#

Tags: c#, object, foreach

Trying to loop through a list of objects using a foreach loop and I've come into trouble as I get a compiler error

> Foreach statement cannot operate on variable object because it does not contain a definition for `GetEnumerator`.

I parse a file to an anonymous List and then use that list in a method.

```
     var list = (from s in File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(a => a.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None))
                     select new
                     {
                         Nbr = s[0].Trim(),
                         Name = s[1].Trim(),
                         Phone = s[2].Trim(),
                         Addr = s[3].Trim()
                     }).ToList();
 findmatch(list);
}
  Public static void findmatch(object list)
 {
  foreach(var entry in list)
```

I also tried to change the code around  like this:

```
foreach(var entry in list.GetType().GetProperties()) as I still get this error
```

Sorry yes I made an edit to recognize that I'm carrying list over to another method.

Comment: You can remove the the `ToList()`, however, it should work with or without.

Comment: If I stub out some data for `File.ReadAllLines(path)`, it works just fine: http://ideone.com/fSb0Na

Comment: **That's not your real code**. This works and compiles perfectly fine. If you want to ask a question on StackOverflow please show a short and complete example allowing to reproduce the problem you are having. Don't oversimplify things.

Comment: I'm parsing all contains of a file to a list so I kinda need that in my linq

Comment: @ERead: I just did a test with a real file, and it still works.  It shouldn't matter to the compiler whether the data comes from `File.ReadAllLines` or a `string` array.

Comment: Nobody cares about those explanations. If you want help, I repeat: **show a short and complete example allowing to reproduce the problem you are having**. A console application with a Main method would be just fine. Otherwise your question gets closed as not a real one. Simple, plain and easy. Exactly as the example we are expecting you to show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, now that you have shown your real code it's clear where the problem is. Anonymous objects cannot leave the local context. You cannot loop over an instance of an `object`. And you cannot use this anonymous object anywhere outside of the context in which this anonymous object is defined in.

So start by defining a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Nbr { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Adr { get; set; }
}
```

then adapt your LINQ query to return an IEnumerable of this model instead of some anonymous object:

```
var list = 
    from s in File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(a => a.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    select new MyModel
    {         
        Nbr = s[0].Trim(),
        Name = s[1].Trim(),
        Phone = s[2].Trim(),
        Addr = s[3].Trim()
    };
findmatch(list);
```

and finally adapt your `findmatch` method to take an IEnumerable of your model instead of some weakly typed object which you cannot iterate over anyways:

```
public static void findmatch(IEnumerable<MyModel> list)
{
    foreach(var entry in list)
    {
        // do whatever you intended to do with the entry previously
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is exactly as described: you can't call an iterator on a variable of type `object`, because it has none. Your method takes an `object`, so you can't do that.

The reason you are using `object`, apparently, it because you are `select`ing into an anonymous type, so you have nothing to declare your `List<T>` as.

What you need to do is define a concrete type, and instead have your method accept `List<MyType>` or `IEnumerable<MyType>` rather than `object`